# Thunar custom command: Keep Terminal open

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, xfce4, thunar

When I make custom commands for Thunar with the `xfce4-terminal -x` command, sometimes I'd like to see the Terminal output of the command. How can I prevent Terminal from closing after the command is run?

I've tried these:

```
xfce4-terminal -x COMMAND &
xfce4-terminal -x COMMAND && read -p
xfce4-terminal -x COMMAND && read -p '' foo
```

They didn't work. Strangely, it won't run the `read` command. It says:

> Failed to execute child process "read" (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use the `--hold` (`-H`) switch for this.

That is, instead of `xfce4-terminal -x command` you would use `xfce4-terminal -H -x command`.

The `-H` switch is described in the man page as:

> Causes the terminal to be kept around after the child command has terminated

You would then close the terminal window normally once you are done reading the output of the command.

Comment: Nice! I'm not sure how I missed that switch in the man page. Maybe it's because it's an `-H`, which is close to the usual `-h` for "help".

Answer (score 1):

The thunar custom action dialog is *not* a shell, so shell built-ins like `&&` and `read` don't work. Wrap them in a proper script with `#!/bin/sh` header and than call the script.

Comment: I accepted the other answer because it's just a little closer to the question, but this solution's solid and would work especially well with complex commands.